# Unsupported architecture - Shared Enum between Metal and Swift

Tags: swift, metal

I try to share an Enum that I defined in an Header File between metal and my swift project:

```
#ifndef SharedIndizes_h
#define SharedIndizes_h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#endif /* SharedIndizes_h */

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, VertexAttribute)
{
    VertexAttributePosition = 0,
    VertexAttributeNormal  = 1,
};
```

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#import "ExchangeTypes/SharedIndizes.h"
using namespace metal;

struct VertexIn {
    float3 position [[ attribute(VertexAttributePosition) ]];
    float3 normal [[ attribute(VertexAttributeNormal) ]];
};
```

```
vertexDescriptor.attributes[VertexAttribute.position.rawValue]
vertexDescriptor.attributes[VertexAttribute.normal.rawValue]
```

But all I get is some unexpected Errors:

- Unsupported architecture
- unknown type name '_int64_t'
- unknown type name '_int32_t'
- ...

Removing `#import "ExchangeTypes/SharedIndizes.h"` from my metal File also removes the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
#ifndef SharedIndizes_h
#define SharedIndizes_h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#endif /* SharedIndizes_h */

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, VertexAttribute)
{
    VertexAttributePosition = 0,
    VertexAttributeNormal  = 1,
};
```

with this:

```
#ifndef SharedIndizes_h
#define SharedIndizes_h

#ifdef __METAL_VERSION__
#define NS_ENUM(_type, _name) enum _name : _type _name; enum _name : _type
#define NSInteger metal::int32_t
#else

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#endif /* __METAL_VERSION__ */
#endif /* SharedIndizes_h */

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, VertexAttribute)
{
    VertexAttributePosition = 0,
    VertexAttributeNormal  = 1,
};
```